# projection of a curved surface on the coordinate plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, projection

In computing double integral, the most important thing is to determine the upper and lower bounds of the integral. In other words, it is to determine the projection of the 3D surface on XOY plane. In most cases, the surface's projection isn't easy to draw out. For example: the ellipsoid $$(ax)^2+(y-bx)^2+(z-cx)^2=r^2$$Its volume can't be easily solved by $\frac{4}{3} \pi abc$, but its projection is also hard to get.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTt8T.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LVjq.png)

Are there a general method to solve the projection of arbitrary 3D surface?

Comment: What makes you think that $a,b,c$ are the principal semiaxes?

Comment: No, they are just arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you have a convex body, you want to eliminate $z$ from the equation. To do this here, we find the curve of points where the tangent plane to the surface is vertical; this will be the *apparent contour* for projection on the $xy$-plane. Since we have a level surface of $f(x,y,z)=(ax)^2 + (y-bx)^2 + (z-cx)^2$, the normal vector will be $\nabla f$, so the points we want satisfy $\partial f/\partial z = 0$, i.e., $z=cx$. The projection into the $xy$-plane of the intersection of this locus with the original surface is the curve
$$(ax)^2 + (y-bx)^2 = r^2,$$
and, by convexity, that gives you the boundary of your projection.

However, I recommend a totally different approach. Use a [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) to compute the volume as the triple integral $\iiint_\Omega 1 dV$. The equation tells us that our region $\Omega$ is the image of the ball $B$ of radius $r$ centered at the origin in $uvw$-space, where $u=ax$, $v=y-bx$, and $w=z-cx$. The Jacobian determinant is easy:
$$\frac{\partial (u,v,w)}{\partial (x,y,z)} = \left|\begin{matrix}a&0&0\\-b&1&0\\-c&0&1\end{matrix}\right| = a,$$
and so
$$\frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (u,v,w)} = \frac1a.$$
Thus,
$$\text{vol}(\Omega) = \iiint_B \left|\frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (u,v,w)}\right| \,du\,dv\,dw = \frac 1a\text{vol}(B) = \frac{4\pi r^3}{3a}.$$

Comment: Thank you  for you help!